# Eclipse failing to run libGDX iOS app

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to run my libGDX roboVM project on an actual device but I'm getting an error:

An internal error occurred during: "Launching -ios (2)".
No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Developer'

Is there a wiki that explains where I can set these signing options?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `robovm` block in build.gradle to include your signing identity name and number, and the name of your provisioning profile:

```
robovm {
    iosSignIdentity = "iPhone Developer: My Name (ABCDEFGHIJ)" 
    //To find iosSignIdentity, run this in terminal: security find-identity -v -p codesigning

    iosProvisioningProfile = "My Developer Profile" 
    //The simple name of the profile. Look in Xcode preferences->accounts.

    iosSkipSigning = false
    stdoutFifo = null
    stderrFifo = null
}
```

Comment: I will try this tonight, although I don't understand two things: why isn't this mentioned in the libgdx wiki? According to the wiki, there is no setup to be done out of the box. And secondly, why would changing the build.gradle do anything for Eclipse? My understanding is Eclipse builds its projects according to its workspace settings, not from looking at the build.gradle files.

Comment: It's not documented well. And it's not necessary to launch to device, only to create an IPA (deployable app file). I don't use Eclipse any more, but I think robovm still looks to the gradle config to find out your signing identity, even though you aren't manually putting in gradle commands.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It doesn't seem to look at this at all. I tried using Gradle to refresh dependencies but no changes. I posted a question in the forums. I can't really use Gradle on my main project since there are other issues with it that I haven't figured out. It seems to not be able to build my BaseGameUtils project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the build.gradle file to include the signing identity and provisioning profile. Just download the [robovm Eclipse plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/robovm-eclipse). There is one for IntelliJ too. When you create your IPA in either Eclipse or IntelliJ you provide your signing identity and provisioning profile.